# How to fix the default height for the collapse body in Ant design

Tags: javascript, css

I created right side collapsible panel. I need to change the panel height (max 100px) after the collapse

My css is like this

```
background: '#f7f7f7', borderRadius: 5, width: 200, marginBottom: 0, border: 50, overflow: 'hidden',
```

and Rekit code like this

```
 render() {
    return (
      <div className="common-coll-bar">
        <Collapse bordered defaultActiveKey={['1']} onChange={callback}>
          <Panel header="This is panel header 1" key="1" style={customPanelStyle}>
            <p>{text}</p>
          </Panel>

        </Collapse>
      </div>
    );
 }
```

can you help me?

Answer (score -1):

!do not use height it will ruin the layout!
Just use line-height

```
.ant-collapse-header {
          line-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: `do not use height it will ruin the layout` - will it? Height = line-height + padding-top + padding-bottom. So, no, same thing in a way. Just means any text will be HUGELY spaced apart by 100px per line

Comment: thanks captain (facepalm)
It's obvious
I wrote a working version!
You can test https://ant.design/components/collapse/
.ant-collapse-header - here you can change both the padding and the line-height
and since there the dependence is due to the line-height, then I said that it is better to change the line-height

And before putting "MINUS" try to test !!!